# Transactions keep accumulating in buffer (Google Analytics SDK for Android)

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

I'm trying to track downloads and sales of my app with Google Analytics. When my app receives an INSTALL_REFERRER broadcast, it creates a transaction and posts it to GA. However even after a successful dispatch, the transactions still accumulate in the buffer, and are re-sent the next time too (I see this in the debug output of the GA Android SDK).

I am not seeing any new transactions in my GA reports. I'm sure the SDK is reaching the GA servers because there is no network error (if I disable the network I get an exception).

Here is my code:

```
    // Send this transaction to Google Analytics
    GoogleAnalyticsTracker tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
    tracker.setDebug(true);
    tracker.startNewSession(context.getString(R.string.analytics_account), context);

    // Construct transaction
    String sku = context.getString(R.string.ime_packagename);
    String orderid = Utils.getDeviceID(context) + "-" + sku + "-" + System.currentTimeMillis();
    float price = 1.99f;
    tracker.addTransaction(new Transaction.Builder( 
        orderid,
        price).build());
    tracker.addItem(new Item.Builder(
        orderid,
        sku,
        price,
        1)
    .setItemName(context.getString(R.string.ime_name))
    .build());

     // Dispatch to GA
    tracker.trackTransactions();
    tracker.dispatch();
    // tracker.clearTransactions(); // Uncommenting this line makes no difference!
    tracker.stopSession();
```

Here is the debug output from the GA SDK for Android. It is dispatching 32 transactions. If I run it again it will dispatch 33 transactions.

```
01-20 17:34:41.895: D/TypeSmart FREE(1930): Referrer is: utm_source=testing&utm_medium=ref_tracker&utm_campaign=testing
01-20 17:34:41.961: I/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(1930): referrer=utm_source=testing&utm_medium=ref_tracker&utm_campaign=testing
01-20 17:34:42.430: D/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(1930): Referrer store attemped succeeded.
01-20 17:34:42.617: V/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(1930): Called dispatch
01-20 17:34:42.645: I/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(1930): Host: www.google-analytics.com
01-20 17:34:42.645: I/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(1930): User-Agent: GoogleAnalytics/1.4.2 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.3; en-ca; SGH-I896 Build/GINGERBREAD)
01-20 17:34:42.645: I/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(1930): GET /__utm.gif?utmwv=4.8.1ma&utmn=2117075971&utmt=tran&utmtid=200142206eb49cfd-com.comet.android.TypeSmart&utmtst=&utmtto=&utmttx=&utmtsp=&utmtci=&utmtrg=&utmtco=&utmac=TypeSmart FREE&utmcc=__utma%3D1.1829447487.1327094937.1327094937.1327094937.1%3B&utmht=1327094937149&utmqt=7545496 HTTP/1.1
01-20 17:34:42.649: V/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(1930): Sending 32 hits to dispatcher
01-20 17:34:42.660: D/TypeSmart FREE(1930): Referrer is: utm_source=testing&utm_medium=ref_tracker&utm_campaign=testing
01-20 17:34:42.660: I/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(1930): referrer=utm_source=testing&utm_medium=ref_tracker&utm_campaign=testing
01-20 17:34:42.742: I/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(1930): Host: www.google-analytics.com
01-20 17:34:42.742: I/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(1930): User-Agent: GoogleAnalytics/1.4.2 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.3; en-ca; SGH-I896 Build/GINGERBREAD)
01-20 17:34:42.742: I/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(1930): GET /__utm.gif?utmwv=4.8.1ma&utmn=101102466&utmt=item&utmtid=200142206eb49cfd-com.comet.android.TypeSmart&utmipc=com.comet.android.TypeSmart&utmipn=TypeSmart%20FREE&utmiva=TypeSmart&utmipr=&utmiqt=1&utmac=TypeSmart FREE&utmcc=__utma%3D1.1829447487.1327094937.1327094937.1327094937.1%3B&utmht=1327094937298&utmqt=7545445 HTTP/1.1
01-20 17:34:42.754: D/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(1930): Referrer store attemped succeeded.
01-20 17:34:42.754: I/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(1930): Host: www.google-analytics.com
01-20 17:34:42.754: I/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(1930): User-Agent: GoogleAnalytics/1.4.2 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.3; en-ca; SGH-I896 Build/GINGERBREAD)
01-20 17:34:42.754: I/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(1930): GET /__utm.gif?utmwv=4.8.1ma&utmn=1136511106&utmt=tran&utmtid=200142206eb49cfd-com.comet.android.TypeSmart&utmtst=&utmtto=&utmttx=&utmtsp=&utmtci=&utmtrg=&utmtco=&utmac=TypeSmart FREE&utmcc=__utma%3D1.1829447487.1327094937.1327094937.1327095148.2%3B&utmht=1327095148884&utmqt=7333867 HTTP/1.1
(31 more dispatches omitted)
```

**UPDATE:** I re-installed the app and the problem disappeared. I will try to identify a pattern if it happens again.

Comment: I've just experienced the same thing. This is an emulator bug to do with it's network connection. Uninstall and re-install cleared it up.

Comment: @Blundell: I experienced this bug on a device. Restarting the app should clear up any network problems, but didn't.

Comment: @casperOne: 12 upvotes in 2 months is a good sign this is not a localized situation.

Comment: Your right, I'm using the EasyTracker lib and the Emulator. Something definitely up the dispatcher is just looping constantly.

Comment: @BarryFruitman ["Update: I reinstalled the app and the problem disappeared.  I will try to identify a pattern if it happens again"](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8949271/4) = Too Localized

Comment: @casperOne: Not consistently reproducible != Too Localized

Comment: @Barry Your issue could have been a broken var with a spave in it, then when you reinstalled that would delete your database and you had fixed the var space in the mean time. My issue was Lint broke my Web ID! I blogged about it here: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/google-analytics-common-problems-and-fixes/ Hope people can find their issue within that list

Comment: Thanks. You should post that as an answer. Oh wait! You can't because casperOne closed this question because it's "too localized". It only affects you, me and the 12 people that upvoted it. :-P