# Database exception from Android SDK for Android

Tags: android, google-analytics

I usually (but not always) see this exception when I use the Google Analytics SDK:

```
01-20 18:00:53.002: E/Database(3750): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.comet.android.TypeSmart/databases/google_analytics.db' 
01-20 18:00:53.002: E/Database(3750): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
```

The Android SDK is being naughty but of course I cannot change it. I'm getting [weird behavior from the SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949271/transactions-keep-accumulating-in-buffer) and I wonder if this is the problem (but if it is, the SDK shouldn't work for anyone!).

Should I be concerned by this exception?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing when I implement the AnalyticsReceiver

Comment: It doesn't seem to be affecting the SDK (the weird behavior I reported was something else), so I think it's safe to ignore.

Answer (score -1):

Try closing the cursor object or the database object whichever is opened somewhere in your class,or method...

```
cursor_object.close();
```

or

```
database_object.close();
```

This error usually comes as when you try to use the same databse or cursor object,you previously declared...Try this simple steps..

Comment: Sorry man....yes you should be concerned,as when the device looks to open the database for second time,it will find the database is already open....does this clear your doubt???

Comment: I understand what the error means but since I cannot fix it (the code is in a Google SDK) I was asking if it's safe to ignore. I've been using the SDK for a while and I think the error is harmless.